# $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial on field $k$, $f(\alpha)=0$. $k'$ is field extension of $k$, then $k(\alpha)\otimes_kk'\cong k'[x]/(f(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, extension-field, tensor-products

$k$ is a field, $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial on $k$, $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$.

If $k'$ is field extension of $k$, then $k(\alpha)\otimes_kk'\cong k'[x]/(f(x))$.

My idea:

Since $f(\alpha)=0$, $f(x)$ is irreducible on $k$, $k(\alpha)\cong k[x]/(f(x))$.

It's sufficient to prove $k[x]/(f(x))_k \otimes_kk'\cong k'[x]/(f(x))_k'$

$(f(x))_k$ means ideal in $k[x]$ generated by $f(x)$, same meaning for $(f(x))_k'$.

Since left side occurs $\otimes$, I think *Base Change* for tensor product might help.

Then how to proceed? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have a natural surjective morphism $k[x]/(f(x)) \otimes_kk'\to k'[x]/(f(x)) $ (sending $\sum_j a_j \otimes_k b_j$ to $\sum_j a_jb_j$). So it reduces to the injectivity. The LHS and RHS are $k$-vector spaces. What are their dimensions and basis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the short exact sequence
$$ 0\longrightarrow k[x]\xrightarrow{\times f(x)} k[x]\longrightarrow k[x]/(f(x))\longrightarrow 0, $$
and tensor by $k'$ (which is flat over $k$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint $1$:

$1$. From property of field extension, $k(\alpha)\cong k[x]/(f(x))$.

$2$. $k[x]\otimes_kk'\cong k'[x]$.

$3$. From *Base Change Formula*, $\cdot \otimes_k k' \cong \cdot \otimes_{k[x]}(k[x]\otimes k')$.

Hint $2$:

$\varphi:k[x]/(f(x))\times k' \to k'[x]/(f(x)), (\bar x,a)\mapsto a\bar x$ induces $\bar \varphi:k[x]/(f(x))\otimes_k k' \to k'[x]/(f(x))$.

"Inverse" of $\bar \varphi$ is given by $\Sigma a_i \bar x^i \mapsto \Sigma \bar x^i \otimes_k a_i.$ Do some check.